# Quicksort index issue

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to implement basic quicksort function. I'm a little bit confused about index range.

```
void q_sort(int * tab, int left, int right)
    {
      if(left < right)
        {
          int piv = left;
          for(int i = left+1; i <= right; ++i)
            if(tab[i] < tab[left])
              change(tab[++piv], tab[i]);

          change(tab[piv],tab[left]);

          q_sort(tab, left, piv-1);
          q_sort(tab, piv+1, right);

        }
    }
```

Let's take an array of four elements. If I call function with

```
q_sort(array, 0, 3)
```

it seems to work but if I change the line

```
for(int i = left+1; i < right; ++i)
```

and call function with

```
q_sort(array, 0, 4)
```

it doesn't.

Isn't it the same range? What's the point?

Comment: That isn't the only place a right-side comparison is done in your algorithm. Consider what `if(left < right)` does with your new parameters, and how it may affect the algorithm. Also consider whether `q_sort(tab, left, piv-1);` may also need changing, and whether you should do *anything* if `(right-left) <= 1` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `q_sort` is recursive, the meaning of its parameters needs to be taken in two contexts:

- When the function is called externally, and
- When a recursive invocation is performed.

You have adjusted the `int right` parameter in the external call `q_sort(array, 0, 4)` to treat the right end as *exclusive*, but the recursive invocation `q_sort(tab, left, piv-1)` assumes that the third parameter is *inclusive*. Remove `-1` from the expression to fix this problem:

```
q_sort(tab, left, piv); // <<== Here
q_sort(tab, piv+1, right);
```

Comment: Im grateful for your help. I can understand this recursive mechanism much better now.